# Как правильно образовать название жителей города?

Tags: словоформы

Есть название города "Черкассы". Как правильно будут называться его жители: 1. черкасчане, 2. черкащане, 3. черкасщане. И, соответственно, местность Черкасчина, Черкащина или Черкасщина. И какими правилами это регламентируется?

Comment: @Kolia, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Да я смотрю этот пользователь и не появлялся здесь после того как задал вопрос. Немного странны для меня подобные случаи.


Хотя, конечно, чтобы увидеть ответ не обязательно заходить на форум, вводя пароль и имя.

Answer (score 3):

Знакомые края! :-)

Говорится: ЧеркАщина и черкащАне. Местные жители нередко так и пишут по-русски, во всяком случае в Интернете. Тем более, что по-украински: *Черкащина*, через "щ".

По-русски всё-таки пишется с буквой "с" : **Черкасщина** и **черкасщане**.

По поводу этнохоронима (т.е. названия жителей) есть разные мнения. Традиционное привычное название жителя и жительницы соответственно **черкасщанин** и **черкасщанка**. С советских времен в городе есть магазин "Черкасщанка".

Новый мер города, не местный, приезжий, по фамилии Одарич, называет жителей города -- *черкасцы*. И особо лояльные местные чиновники следом за ним. Причём есть мнение, что *черкасщане* -- это жители области. Звучит несколько странновато для коренных местных жителей, по моему скромному мнению.

*"Черкасцы"* и *"черкасщане"* -- это аналогично названию жителей Крыма. "Крымцы"(кримци) и более привычное *крымчане*. Если во втором варианте понятно, как образовывать женский род -- крымчанка и черкасщанка, -- то в первом случае не совсем ясно. Крымка? Черкаска?

Answer (score 0):

В советские времена, когда русский язык был официальным, писали "Черкасщина", "черкасщане". По-украински писали "черкасці". Сейчас стали писать по-русски "Черкасчина", "черкасчане", что мне кажется неправильным. По-украински, как только СМИ перестали позволять себе содержать корректора, стали писать "черкащани", думаю, под влиянием русского языка.

Comment: Оно, конечно, так... Смысл есть. Если Полтавщина или там, Херсонщина пишутся через Щ, то  чем Черкассы лучше/хуже?! Но хотелось бы уточнить источник этих ваших наблюдений. Я не могу подтвердить ни советской нормы, ни тем более того, что вы называете "сейчас стали писать".